# Drupal 7 - Hide delete button on all content types

Tags: php, drupal-7, hook-form-alter

I would like to Remove delete button on all content types in admin panel using small custom code.Please help.

Comment: I want to remove the delete link on the content type listing in admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom module and use **hook_form_alter**. This module must run after all other modules that alter the forms. Example:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form); // Use this to find the $form_id using Devel module if you like
  if ($form_id == "MY_FORM_ID")  {
   $form['actions']['delete']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

For a complete set of options see at [Specify $form elements to be excluded from display?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/41748/12163)

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? If so please give some feedback (upvote, select as acceptable).